# Python Programming Help for a beginner?

Tags: python, methods, area

SO I need to find the area of the rectangle. I must put a method in the Rectangle class called "CalcArea()" that multiplies the width * height. I have no clue how to do this and I'm so lost the book doesn't explain how to do this at all. Here's my code:

```
class Point():
    x = 0.0
    y = 0.0

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        print("Point Constructor")

    def ToString(self):
        return "{X:" + str(self.x) + ",Y:" + str(self.y) + "}"

class Ellipse(Point):
    radiusV = 0.0
    radiusH = 0.0

    def __init__(self, x, y, radiusV, radiusH):
        super().__init__(x,y)
        self.radiusV = radiusV
        self.radiusH = radiusH
        print("Ellipse Constructor")

    def ToString(self):
        return super().ToString() + \
                ",{Radius: Vertical = " + str(self.radiusV) + ", Radius: Horizontal = " +     str(self.radiusH) + "}"
p = Point(50,50)
print(p.ToString())
e = Ellipse(80,80,60,80)
print(e.ToString())

class Size():
    width = 0.0
    height = 0.0

    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        print ("Size Constructor")

    def ToString(self):
        return "{Width = " + str(self.width) + \
               ", Height = " + str(self.height) + "}"

class Rectangle(Point, Size):
    area = 0.0

    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        Point.__init__(self,x,y)
        Size.__init__(self,width,height)
        print("Rectangle Constructor")


    def ToString(self):
        return Point.ToString(self) + "," + Size.ToString(self) + 
s = Size (80,70)
print(s.ToString())

r = Rectangle(200,250,40,50)
print(r.ToString())
```

Comment: Your code is incorrectly indented. Can you correct it? Don't omit white spaces, better still would be to paste the code as it is.

Comment: @sidi Unless it has tabs instead of spaces, then fix it to just have spaces before pasting.

Comment: Honestly in the editor it was fine but the website is having major trouble taking the code so I had to manually put spaces in each line... majorly annoying lol. But still can anyone help with the actual problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Rectangle` class use the following method

```
def calcArea(self):
    return self.width * self.height
```

To print the area simply call
`print mRectangle.calcArea()`

where `mRectangle` is an instance of the `Rectangle` class.

`self.width` and `self.height` are available to you since `Rectangle` inherits from `Size` class and `Size` has the instance variables `width` and `height` set appropriately in its constructor. These values are available to you since `Rectangle` is a subclass of `Size`.

Also your `width = 0` and `height = 0` in Size class might not be doing exactly what you think. They are static or class variables in Python and completely different from `self.width` and `self.height` Here is an example to illustrate that

```
>>> class MyClass():
...     a = 0
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.a = 5
...     def echo(self):
...         print MyClass.a, self.a
... 
>>> instance = MyClass()
>>> instance.echo()
0 5
>>> instance.a
5
>>> MyClass.a
0
>>>
```

In python you access class or static variables with the syntax `ClassName.Variable` and can be accessed without creating an object of that class. Where as an instance variable can be called only with an instance of the class.